# How can I transform this table into this specific format using PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have an `Excel` Table in the following format:

```
Code     Rank      MonthYr
 A        5        2018-10-01
 B        10       2018-10-01
 C        7        2018-10-01
 A        4        2018-11-01
 B        15       2018-11-01
 C        2        2018-11-01
```

I want to transform the table into the following format:

```
 Code     2018-10-01     2018-11-01
  A           5              4
  B           10             15
  C           7              2
```

I have tried the "Unpivot" features of PowerQuery but without success.
Can this be done with `PowerQuery`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `Unpivot`, but `Pivot` for this. In Power Query Editor select `MonthYr` column and click `Pivot Column`, then select `Rank` as values column:

[image]

And you will get the desired result:

[image]